# How do I update a meteor app deployed on modulus.io without having it restart or stop functioning?

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

I find that whenever I `modulus deploy` my app, after it has uploaded to apply the new changes the app throws some connection errors in the console due to it being restarted.

Is there a way to update deployed meteor apps without having the entire app restart in production?

It looks like whenever I change one line of code i need to redeploy the entire app. I can live with that for now but main issue is the restarting whenever an update is made.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't possible (as of 4th July 2016).

Rolling deployments are available through the "Enterprise Class" package that modulus offers. You have to get in touch with them and discuss your requirements. I'm not sure how much this costs, but it might be worth getting in touch and checking.

The modulus devs have mentioned that rolling deployments might be something they look into. You can see some discussion on it on [github](https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/issues/82).

Edit: As a side note for anyone coming across this... I would suggest not using modulus (or xervo now) for hosting meteor apps. We ran a production app with them for a few months before migrating to AWS due to a high number of issues that were out of our control.